# triangle area calculator, It keeps showing 0, why?

Tags: c, initialization, printf, integer-arithmetic

I am making a triangle area calculator, but it only show 0 instead of answer, It must be the formula 1/2 * ab sin c , can someone tell me what should I change to make it work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
float main ()
  {
float a,b,c,pi ;
printf("Enter a : ");
scanf("%f",&a);
printf("Enter b : ");
scanf("%f",&b); 
printf("Enter c :");
scanf("%f",&c);
printf("%f\n",(a*(1/2)*b*(c*pi)/180));
  
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the value of pi?!

Comment: The expression inside `(1/2)` is **integer** division, with a result of zero. Make it `(1.0/2)`, or even just `0.5`.

Comment: Using `float main()` is highly unorthodox — I don't know of a system where it is supported.  Use `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 2):

The sub-expression (1/2) is always equal to 0 due to the integer arithmetic. You need to write for example `(1.0f/2)`.

Apart from this the variable `pi` is not initialized

```
float a,b,c,pi ;
```

Also according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int  main( void )
```